# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "AnnotationDatabaseImpl"

Tags: android

When I install debug version of android app, its working fine.
But with release version its giving this exception.

Any solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

```
        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.cheezburger.icanhas, PID: 9460
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cheezburger.icanhas/com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.activities.BuilderActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use annotation database(s)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3256)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3352)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use annotation database(s)
        at roboguice.RoboGuice.initializeAnnotationDatabaseFinderAndHierarchyTraversalFilterFactory(RoboGuice.java:292)
        at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:149)
        at roboguice.RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RoboGuice.java:90)
        at roboguice.RoboGuice.getInjector(RoboGuice.java:197)
        at com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.activities.RoboActivity.onCreate(RoboActivity.java:90)
        at com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.activities.BuilderActivity.onCreate(BuilderActivity.java:88)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6877)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
```

Proguard Code:

```
Proguard code:
        -keepattributes **
        -keep interface com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.** { *; }
        -keep class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.activities.** { *; }
        -keep, allowobfuscation class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.adapter.** { *; }
        -keep, allowobfuscation class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.android.utils.** { *; }
        -keep, allowobfuscation class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.controllers.** { *; }
        -keep class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.dependencies.interfaces.** { *; }
        -keep interface com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.dependencies.interfaces.** { *; }
        -keep, allowobfuscation class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.dialogs.** { *; }
        # maybe keep?
        -keep, allowobfuscation class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.dto.** { *; }
        -keep, allowobfuscation class com.cheezburger.icanhas.builder.models.** { *; }
        -keep, allowobfuscation class qwerjk.better_text.** { *; }

        #-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
        -keep class roboguice.activity
        -keep public class roboguice.AnnotationDatabaseImpl { *; }
        -keep public class AnnotationDatabaseImpl { *; }
```

Comment: post some code..!!

Comment: you are using roboguice? if yes what version?

Comment: org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1

Comment: the error is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use annotation database(s)` There is something wrong in `roboguice.AnnotationDatabaseImpl`'s code

Comment: maybe -keepattributes *Annotation* ?